# Difference between significance and contribution

Tags: model

"What is the difference between "significance" and "contribution" of individual variable to a outcome variable?

How to address this while creating a prediction model basically.I understand contribution made by a variable towards the outcome, which shoudl be considered while creating a model but not sure of how "significance" is different from this.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the simple regression

\begin{align*}
y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2,
\end{align*}
where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two variables that affect the outcome variable $y$. You would use the standard regression concepts and obtain estimates for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2},$ say. These values would be the "contribution". If $x_1$ increased by 1 unit then $y$ increases by (approximately) $\hat{\beta_1}$ units. So the value of $\hat{\beta_1}$ gives an indication of the contribution of $x_1$.

To test whether variable $x_1$ is significant, the following test is used:
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{H}_0:\beta_1=0\quad\text{vs}\quad\mathrm{H}_1:\beta_1\ne 0.
\end{equation*}
If the null hypothesis is not rejected, then $x_1$ is not statistically significant. A $p$-value would give a measure of significance. If $p<0.05$ then $x_1$ is significant and a smaller value implies a larger significance.

Comment: I don't think we can conclude anything if the hypothesis is not rejected.